# The current request for action {0} on controller type {1} is ambiguous

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have two actions and I want my routes `/users` and `/users/{id}` to be different. However it throws me error.

Is it possible implement this sorta thing without manually creating *every* route, I will have other controllers that will follow similar pattern and writing custom routes for all of them seems redundant and bad idea in general.

### Error

> The current request for action 'Index' on controller type
>   'UsersController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index() on type
>   Api.Controllers.UsersController System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   Index(Int32) on type Api.Controllers.UsersController

### Code

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: when you specified /users/{id} did you have id = UrlParameter.Optional?

Comment: @AlexeyAza I have default routing set up. If I add another route where I delete `id = UrlParameter.Optional` it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @AlexeyAza they suggest to use separate actions or check inside the controller if id is null. It doesn't really answer what I'm trying to achieve. Maybe there is no way to fix this. However they did that in WebAPI somehow..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an `ActionMethodSelector`:

```
public class RequiresParameterAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute {

   readonly string parameterName;

   public RequiresParameterAttribute(string parameterName) {
      this.parameterName = parameterName;
   }

   public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo) {
      return controllerContext.RouteData.Values[parameterName] != null;
   }
}
```

And the controller:

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return null;
    }

    [RequiresParameter("id")]
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if the above will work, but should give you an idea.

Comment: I put the codes in RouteConfig.cs, and it work great.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try something like this:

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{   
    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        if(id == null) {
            // case A
        }
        else {
            // case B
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a much simpler solution than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Max Toro's answer was useful, although I needed to specify more parameters.

I changed the selector attribute to this:

```
public class RequiresParameterAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{

    readonly string[] parameterName;

    public RequiresParameterAttribute(string[] parameterName)
    {
        this.parameterName = parameterName;
    }

    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {

        //somehow, in my version of MVC controllerContext.RouteData.Values was not returning querystring parameters at all...
        var queryString = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString; 

        foreach (string param in parameterName)
        {
            if (queryString.GetValues(param) == null)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

And then it can be used as such:

```
[RequiresParameter(new string[] { "id", "id2", "id3" })]
public ActionResult Index(int id, int id2, int id3)
{
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put [HttpGet] for the first method!

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet] 
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do this and try to post a form on /Index to /Index with the form using GET, it never hits the second "Index" action because the first one is catching it. So this doesn't work in all circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

I'd just delete the first method that takes no parameters and make the integer both optional in the routing and a nullable int in the controller. Then you can decide what to do based on the integer being null in a single action method.

You can define the action as part of the route:

```
/{action}/{id}
```

And make `action` required but `id` optional... that would allow for mapping of action based on URL. Could also specify `{controller}`.

Comment: It would be my last resort. This seems like a bad controller design.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your other, similar routes?

Comment: `/projects` and `/projects/{id}` etc

Comment: well it does help but it changes the routing. I want my urls to be rest-like.

Comment: They could be still... You could have different methods for GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE...

Comment: Can you post the exact routes for this? I tested it and it didn't work the way I expected.

Comment: Decorate each action method with action attributes: `[HttpGet]`, `[HttpPost]`, etc.

Comment: I highly recommend that you read the tutorials at http://www.asp.net/mvc - you are lacking some basics here and this question is becoming a discussion of core concepts. I've given you the answer to your original question.