# Why my overload controller methods not hitting properly?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have view name called `PrintPatientConsent.aspx`. I need to call it for two types.

But, by default only default action method only called. even though i passed parameters.

For your reference:

```
 [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
 public ActionResult PrintPatientConsent()
 {
   ----
 }

 [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
 [ActionName("PrintPatientConsent")] // i tried to pass action name
 public ActionResult PrintPatientConsent(int id)
 {
   ------
 }
```

Javascript:-

Ex-Code:

```
url = '/Emr/Patients/PrintPatientConsent?Id=' + idd; //where i'm calling Parameterized actionmethod
TopUp.display(url)
```

Can any one please help me to find out the solution.., thanx in advance.

Comment: You only need one method - `public ActionResult PrintPatientConsent(int? id)` (and you can check if a value has been passed by using `if(id.HasValue)`

Comment: remove the actionname and try

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers- i tried by removing action name.., even it call only default action method ..

Comment: have you try to put in your url string not `Id` but `id`?

Comment: You can also try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457710/the-current-request-for-action-0-on-controller-type-1-is-ambiguous/17460986#17460986

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solutions is

```
    public ActionResult PrintPatientConsent(int? id)
    {
        if(id == null) {
            // case A
        }
        else {
           // case B
        }
    }
```

You can also use the method selection attribute: [The current request for action {0} on controller type {1} is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457710/the-current-request-for-action-0-on-controller-type-1-is-ambiguous/17460986#17460986)